# How can I benchmark a server listening to a unix socket file?

Tags: sockets, benchmarking, unix-socket

With http servers, I use apache-bench to benchmark the server configuration, for e.g.

```
ab -T application/json -c 100 -n 10000 http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Server Software:
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        22 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   1.580 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      1390000 bytes
HTML transferred:       220000 bytes
Requests per second:    6327.40 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       15.804 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.158 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          858.90 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    7   2.9      6      22
Processing:     1    9   3.2      8      31
Waiting:        0    7   2.9      6      29
Total:          3   16   4.9     15      44

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     15
  66%     16
  75%     17
  80%     18
  90%     21
  95%     24
  98%     30
  99%     41
 100%     44 (longest request)
```

I now have a server with is configured to listen to a `.sock` file, which works, I can send requests and I get back responses, but how can I benchmark the connection to see things like requests per second and other information like the above?

I ask because I have quite a few configurations of the socket server, and want to choose the best configuration based on actual numbers.

Comment: If `ab` does not support unix domain sockets, could you use `curl` for benchmarking? It have option `--unix-socket` for  using unix domain sockets.